# Select and order values

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a table of values, tasks, which I need to pull from a database, and then order as follows:

```
                <section class="entry-content">
                <header>    
                    <h4>Daily</h4>          
                </header>       

                <ul class="task-list" id="daily-tasks">
                    <% @daily.each do |task| %>
                        <% if task.status == "incomplete" %>                    
                            <li><% = task.title %></li>     
                        <% end %>
                    <% end %>

                    <% @daily.each do |task| %>
                        <% if task.status == "complete" %>                  
                            <li><% = task.title %></li>
                        <% end %>
                    <% end %>
                </ul>                           
            </section><!--.entry-content-->
```

I also have once, weekly, monthly, and potentially yearly tasks.

I'm new to Ruby, so I'm looking for the *best* way of doing this, as my current code isn't ideal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this can help you... I will suggest to use an application helper because you are trying to do the same task several times. I didnt test it, but its the complete idea.

**Controller**

```
@daily = Task.where("type = 'daily'")
@weekly =  Task.where("type = 'weekly'")
```

**View**

```
<ul>
 <%= print_task (@daily,'completed') %> 
</ul>

<ul>
 <%= print_task (@daily,'incomplete') %> 
</ul>

<ul>
 <%= print_task (@weekly,'completed') %>           
</ul>

<ul>
 <%= print_task (@weekly,'incomplete') %> 
</ul>   
...
```

**application_helper**

```
def print_task(tasks, status)
 html =''
 tasks.each do |task|
   html += '<li>'
     if task.status == status
       html += "#{task.title}"
      end
   html += '</li>'
 end
 html.html_safe
end
```

Comment: I'll post up my final solution, but this looks like a good start.  In terms of database calls, is there a more efficient way or is it better to do a couple more specific calls than one large result?

Comment: You need to be aware of the your server memory because one hit to retrieve all the information of the database could take a while and if you are thinking on millions of records this will take a hell for loading. For improving rails apps you need to do more specific queries that limit the amount of information and I think you should split some views one for the daily taks, another for the weekly and so on, in that way you will do less queries and save time as well. Hope it helps.

Comment: OK, great.  I'll do specific queries and then look into caching too.  Really appreciate the response